# Clojure join fails to create a string from the result of filter function

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to write a function that takes a string and returns a result of a filter function (I'm working through [4clojure](https://www.4clojure.com) problems). The result must be a string too.

I've written this:

```
(fn my-caps [s]
  (filter #(Character/isUpperCase %) s))

(my-caps "HeLlO, WoRlD!")

Result: (\H \L \O \W \R \D)
```

Now I'm trying to create a string out of this list, using clojure.string/join, like this:

```
(fn my-caps [s]
  (clojure.string/join (filter #(Character/isUpperCase %) s)))
```

The result is however the same. I've also tried using `apply str`, with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defn my-caps [s]
  (->> (filter #(Character/isUpperCase %) s)
       (apply str)))
```

`filter` function returns a lazy sequence. If you want to get a `string`, you should transform the sequence to string by applying `str` function.

Comment: Thanks! It made me look up double arrow-threading macro. I didn't know about thread macros before.

Comment: @ntalbs, why use the `->>` operator here? a simple function call is enough to invoke `apply`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Yes, you're right. The result is the same. However, using `->>` makes it easier to read the code reading, and typing as of my thought process. That's it. It's a kind of personal preferences.

Answer (score 4):

You have to convert the lazy sequence returned by `filter` into a string, by applying the `str` function. Also, use `defn` to define a new function - here's how:

```
(defn my-caps [s]
  (apply str (filter #(Character/isUpperCase %) s)))
```

It works as expected:

```
(my-caps "HeLlO, WoRlD!")
=> "HLOWRD"
```

Answer (score 4):

The last code snippet you pasted works fine. `join` indeed does return a string.

Comment: You're right. Up until now I've been reloading the file to REPL but only after I actually restarted it it worked. The thread wasn't a waste though - I've learned new ways of creating string from a collection.